# C# Integer list solution

Tags: c#, list

I have list

```
List<int> listnumbers
```

with values `{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 }`.

In some cases i need to add new value for existing values in list example , 0 => 5, 1 => 6 ....

Is there way to do that?

EDIT

i want number to

number 0 have stake 5
number 1 have stake 6

But i cannot that declare on begining of  program , only in some cases i woud join stakes

EDIT 2

I will use multidimensional array so it will be

```
0=>5
1=>6
array[0][0] = 0;
array[0][1] = 5;
array[1][0] = 1;
array[1][1] = 6;
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please provide the expected output.

Comment: The update hasn't helped. What is a "stake"? Write some pseudo-code showing what you intend to do with the list.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this could do what you're looking for. You need some kind of data structure to store the additional information:

```
public class NumberLink {
   int Value { get; set; }
   int Link { get; set; }
}

List<NumberLink> numberLinks =
   new List<int> {
      0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
   }
   .Select(i => new NumberLink { Value = i })
   .ToList();

numberLinks.First(nl => nl.Value == 0).Link = 5;
numberLinks.First(nl => nl.Value == 1).Link = 6
```

Please note that if you will always have a range of numbers from 0..n, you don't need this. You can simply use the position of the item in the list to represent the first value, such that a list `{ 5, 6 }` indicates that `0` goes to `5` and `1` goes to `6`.

Comment: No i want to link values to existed if is possible, for example number 1 in list need to have 6

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: OP seems to want to link the values - in that case this shouldn't be an answer, as it doesn't answer the question. "I need to know more about how you intend to use these links before I could suggest a solution." is a perfect example of something that should be a comment.

Comment: ok , i will update question within few minuts

Comment: @nhouser9 It was a perfectly valid answer to the totally-unclear question that was originally asked. We only learned that is wasn't an answer when the asker clarified. If and when the asker actually writes an explanation that's intelligible, if I don't quickly update my answer to something useful, feel free to down-vote or comment again recommending deletion. In any case, my answer was NOT a non-answer when I first wrote it--only question creep made it so, which is not my fault.

Comment: @ErikE It is your fault because you saw his comment, and updated your answer to include information that was not an answer. At the very least your update should have been a comment.

Comment: @nhouser9 I have made this kind of answer many times in the past--when I am able to give a partial answer but need some clarification before fleshing it out. Thank you for the feedback, though I'm comfortable with it as is--though feel free to flag it or downvote as your conscience dictates. I definitely will think about what you've said for future answers.

Comment: @nhouser9 Oh, and notice I edited my post before the asker commented... so your assessment seems to fall short.

Comment: @nhouser9 P.S. I have updated my answer again, anyway, as promised.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want to add some constant value to each element of a list and return it as a new list.

```
List<int> answer = listnumbers.Select(x => x+valueToBeAdded).ToList();
```

The above statement adds a constant to all elements of the list and returns it as a new list.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to **substitute** a value for another, you could use Linq, something along the lines of:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(){0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
var fromValue = 0;
var toValue = 7;
list = list.Select( x => x = (x == fromValue ? toValue : x)).ToList();
//- list = {7,1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

Here the Select statement will mutate your existing list and return a modified list of integers where every value that's equal to `fromValue` will be replaced with `toValue`

Answer (score 0):

CASE 1. To add them at the end of the list:

```
listnumbers.Add(5);
listnumbers.Add(6);
```

list will be `listnumbers ==> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 5, 6 }`

CASE 2. To insert them at a specific position:

```
listnumbers.Insert(0, 5);
listnumbers.Insert(0, 6);
```

list will be `listnumbers ==> { 6, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 }`

CASE 3. To insert them at position that maintains an ordered list (min to max):

```
listnumbers.Insert(listnumbers.FindIndex(0, x => x == 5) + 1, 5);
listnumbers.Insert(listnumbers.FindIndex(0, x => x == 6) + 1, 6);
```

list will be `listnumbers ==> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 }` and in this case, I am using predicates within FindIndex method.